# How to add a priority to react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, components

I want my Home component to load first and then everything else? How can I achieve this?

Or can I load resources in the background while I'm showing a spinner and then show the whole page? Something like this..

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 2500);
  }, []);

  return isLoading ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <div className="App">WholePage</div>
```

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish? Your browser will take some time to render the DOM. That is happening synchronously. And your requests to fetch data will take some time, which happens asynchronously. You can use a spinner to indicate the latter but there is no use for a spinner while the DOM is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use the useEffect hook for the priority component that you want to load first and set a state in there to load the remaining components.

My code would look something like this:

```
    function App(){
    
   const [homeLoaded,setHomeLoaded] = useState(false)

  const getHomeLoaded = (homeLoaded) => {

     setHomeLoaded(homeLoaded)
  } 

   return(
     <>
       <Home gethomeLoaded = {getHomeLoaded}/>

     {homeLoaded ? <OtherComponents>:null}
     </>
   )
}
```

The home component would look something like this:

```
function Home(){

useEffect(() => {
    props.getHomeLoaded(true)
  }, []);

  return(
  <div>Your home content goes here</div>
)
}
```

What I am essentially doing is passing a state to the parent component from Home so that I can set homeLoaded to true only after Home component is loaded